# Some Recyclerview Items Affect Each Other

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview

I have recyclerview with many items. And this is a screenshot of my application, showing the first item of my recyclerview.
[pict of my page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tQBPX.png)

but when I change the choice of the fifth item, the choice of the first item is changing too. Any idea why this is happening? And what should I do?

**this is my adapter:**

```
public class SkoringAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<SkoringAdapter.SkoringViewHolder>{
private List<Skoring> skoringList;
private Context context;
public SkoringAdapter(final Context context) {
    this.skoringList = new ArrayList<>();
    this.context = context;
}
public void setSkoringList(List<Skoring> skoringList){
    this.skoringList.clear();
    this.skoringList.addAll(skoringList);
    notifyDataSetChanged();
}
static class SkoringViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{
    Context context;
    TextView tvSoal, tvKe, tvTotal, tvProses;
    RadioGroup rgPilihan;
    RadioButton rb1, rb2, rb3, rb4, rb5, rb6;
    SkoringViewHolder(View itemView, final Context context) {
        super(itemView);
        this.context = context;
        tvSoal = itemView.findViewById(R.id.tvSoal);
        ...etc
    }
}
@NonNull
@Override
public SkoringViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View itemView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.item_skoring, parent, false);
    return new SkoringViewHolder(itemView,context);
}
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull final SkoringViewHolder holder, final int position) {
    final Skoring tg = skoringList.get(position);
    holder.tvSoal.setText(tg.getSoal());
    holder.tvKe.setText(Integer.toString(position + 1));
    holder.tvTotal.setText(Integer.toString(skoringList.size()));
    holder.rgPilihan.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    holder.rb1.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    holder.rb2.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    holder.rb3.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    holder.rb4.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    holder.rb5.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    holder.rb6.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    String[] kunci = tg.getKunci().split("`");
    String[] pilihan = new String[kunci.length];
    String[] isi = new String[kunci.length];
    String[] skor = new String[kunci.length];
    for (int i=0; i<kunci.length; i++){
        String[] pisah = kunci[i].split("~");
        if(pisah.length == 3){
            pilihan[i] = pisah[0]; isi[i] = pisah[1]; skor[i] = pisah[2];
        }
    }
    holder.rgPilihan.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    if(kunci.length > 0){
        holder.rb1.setText(isi[0]);
        holder.rb1.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        if(kunci.length > 1){
            holder.rb2.setText(isi[1]);
            holder.rb2.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            if(kunci.length > 2){
                holder.rb3.setText(isi[2]);
                holder.rb3.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                if(kunci.length > 3){
                    holder.rb4.setText(isi[3]);
                    holder.rb4.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    if(kunci.length > 4){
                        holder.rb5.setText(isi[4]);
                        holder.rb5.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                        if(kunci.length > 5){
                            holder.rb6.setText(isi[5]);
                            holder.rb6.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                        }}}}}}}}
```

**And this is my item_skoring.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
<androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
    android:layout_margin="16dp"
    app:cardCornerRadius="8dp">
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="16dp">
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tvSoal"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:fontFamily="sans-serif-medium"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:textAlignment="center"
            android:textColor="@color/colorBlack"
            android:textSize="17sp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"/>
        <RadioGroup
            android:visibility="visible"
            android:id="@+id/rgPilihan"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:orientation="vertical">
            <RadioButton
                android:id="@+id/rb1"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textSize="16sp"
                android:visibility="gone"
                android:buttonTint="@color/colorPrimary"/>
            <RadioButton
                android:textSize="16sp"
                android:visibility="gone"
                android:id="@+id/rb2"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:buttonTint="@color/colorPrimary"/>
            <RadioButton
                android:textSize="16sp"
                android:visibility="gone"
                android:id="@+id/rb3"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:buttonTint="@color/colorPrimary"/>
            <RadioButton
                android:textSize="16sp"
                android:visibility="gone"
                android:id="@+id/rb4"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:buttonTint="@color/colorPrimary"/>
            <RadioButton
                android:textSize="16sp"
                android:visibility="gone"
                android:id="@+id/rb5"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:buttonTint="@color/colorPrimary"/>
            <RadioButton
                android:textSize="16sp"
                android:visibility="gone"
                android:id="@+id/rb6"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:buttonTint="@color/colorPrimary"/>
        </RadioGroup>
        <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
            android:id="@+id/tiTelp"
            android:visibility="gone"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">
            <EditText
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:inputType="number"
                android:ems="10"
                android:hint="No. Telepon"
                android:id="@+id/etTelp"
                android:drawablePadding="5dp"
                android:layout_weight="0.85" />
        </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>
        <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
            android:id="@+id/tiHP"
            android:visibility="gone"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="15dp">
            <EditText
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:inputType="number"
                android:ems="10"
                android:hint="No. Handphone"
                android:id="@+id/etHP"
                android:drawablePadding="5dp"
                android:layout_weight="0.85"/>
        </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>
        <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
            android:id="@+id/tiEmail"
            android:visibility="gone"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="15dp">
            <EditText
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:inputType="textEmailAddress"
                android:ems="10"
                android:hint="Alamat Email"
                android:id="@+id/etEmail"
                android:drawablePadding="5dp"
                android:layout_weight="0.85"/>
        </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>
        <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
            android:id="@+id/tiNPWP"
            android:visibility="gone"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="15dp">
            <EditText
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:inputType="phone"
                android:ems="10"
                android:hint="No. NPWP"
                android:id="@+id/etNPWP"
                android:drawablePadding="5dp"
                android:layout_weight="0.85"/>
        </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
</androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    android:padding="10dp"
    android:background="@color/colorGreyUp"
    android:gravity="center">
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Data ke "
        android:textStyle="italic"
        android:textColor="@color/colorBlack"/>
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/tvKe"
        android:textStyle="italic|bold"
        android:textColor="@color/colorBlack"/>
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text=" dari "
        android:textStyle="italic"
        android:textColor="@color/colorBlack"/>
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvTotal"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textStyle="italic|bold"
        android:textColor="@color/colorBlack"/>
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text=" data"
        android:textStyle="italic"
        android:textColor="@color/colorBlack"/>
</LinearLayout>
<TextView
    android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
    android:textColor="@color/colorWhite"
    android:visibility="gone"
    android:padding="14dp"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="SELANJUTNYA"
    android:textSize="18sp"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:id="@+id/bProses"
    android:textAlignment="center"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"/>
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: can you also share your `item_skoring` xml file?

Comment: done @RickSanchez

Comment: Set your item_skoring Size fixed insted

Answer (score 1):

Solved with adding this on my java class:

```
MyrecyclerView.setItemViewCacheSize(100);
```

Comment: Looks like there is no other choice :/. In my case I am applying some special operations to some recyclerView items but other items sometimes get affected. Actually adapter is applying the operation to whichever item it wants. Such an awfull design bug from Google's Android Developers..